# How to set equal height in css when content differs

Tags: html, css, angular

**I want to display cards in the same height even when the content(pattern-name) differs.I'm getting the content from DB.
Here is my html code**

```
<div class="wrapper" *ngFor="let row of Pattern,I">
   <div class="profile-card">
      <div class="profile-card__unit-description">
         <fa-icon 
          size="3x" 
          [icon]="faBrain" 
          class="icon"></fa-icon>
      </div>
      <div class="profile-card__unit-name">{{row.Pattern_Name}}</div> //This pattern name I'm getting it from DB.
      <a class="fancy-button bg-gradient1" *ngIf="arr[row.Pattern_Id] == 1" onclick="return false">
        <span (click)="onselect(row)">
          <i size="2x" class="fa fa-ticket" ></i>Start
        </span>
      </a>
  </div>  
</div>
```

**Here is my CSS for wrapper and profile-card**

```
.wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 50px;
    padding-top: 100px;
    padding-bottom: 80px;
}

.wrapper:focus {
   outline: 0;
}

.profile-card {
    background: white;
    width: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 19px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: -1px 15px 30px -12px black;
    height:inherit;
}

.profile-card__unit-name {
    font-size: 22px;
    color: black;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:15px;
    height:inherit;
}

.profile-card__unit-description {
    padding: 20px;
    color:#F9C118;
}
```

**Please help me in doing that. Thanks in advance**

Comment: Have you tried setting a constant height for your card? `height: 500px;` or `height: 50%;`. Also add an overflow to the card to prevent elements from getting out of the card. `overflow: auto`.

Comment: Which elements you want to take same height... Unit name and unit description??

Comment: Have you tried flex-box? Flexbox will make child elements the same height.

Comment: Yes, I did that @hrishikeshpaul. Still, the height differs

Comment: Yes, I need to set fixed height for unit name and decsription@Atul

Comment: one last thing, these 2 items will be side by side? or up and down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as of now I did not get the reply from you that you want these 2 items side by side or up and down, so just seeing your code, I am assuming that you need it side by side.

so in your case just use `display: flex;` and flex-child will take the same height which will be side by side, to make last-child anchor below use `flex-wrap: wrap` and it will go down as first 2 items will take 50% width each.

I have given both div's background color just for demo purpose so that you can see these are taking equal height.

```css
.wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 50px;
    padding-top: 100px;
    padding-bottom: 80px;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper:focus {
   outline: 0;
}

.profile-card {
    background: white;
    width: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 19px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: -1px 15px 30px -12px black;
    height:inherit;
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.profile-card__unit-name {
    font-size: 22px;
    width: 50%;
    color: black;
    margin-top:0px;
    padding-top: 20px;
background: green;
}

.profile-card__unit-description {
    padding: 20px;
    width: 50%;
    color:#F9C118;
    background: red;
}

.fancy-button {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper" *ngFor="let row of Pattern,I">
   <div class="profile-card">
      <div class="profile-card__unit-description">
      <p>dummy data for demo onlydummy data for demo onlydummy data for demo onlydummy data for demo onlydummy</p>
         <fa-icon 
          size="3x" 
          [icon]="faBrain" 
          class="icon"></fa-icon>
      </div>
      <div class="profile-card__unit-name">row Pattern_Name</div> 
      <a class="fancy-button bg-gradient1">
        <span (click)="onselect(row)">
          <i size="2x" class="fa fa-ticket" ></i>Start
        </span>
      </a>
  </div>  
</div>
```

if need something else, feel free to share

Comment: Thanks, @Atul, yes I wanted it to be side by side, with 3 cards per row.  It's working, but the border has been disappeared for the card

Comment: That I removed .. u can add it again

Comment: Okay and one more thing, I've written code to disable start button, once it is clicked. It returns false and the start button won't appear on the card. Even then I want to maintain the same card height. Can that be done?

Comment: So as I can understand.. in case of not seeing it you are making it's display none, Right? If yes then don't just because display none will remove it's height and width from dom or you can say it's box-sizing, so in place of display none just use visibility:hidden; it will maintain it's place and height and width... One more thing... If this answer helped you... Don't forget to mark it as right answer.

Comment: Yeah sure @Atul. I've updated the code. I've used some condition to disable the button. Can you tell me how to maintain it's height in this case?

Comment: As I can see, you have used ngif on button. So if your condition will not match then it will not render and you can not do anything. In 2nd case, if your ngif condition will true and button appears then on click you can add a css class on this and pass CSS like this, .fancy-button { visibility:visible; pointer-event:none;}, it will do the trick., But one thing is strange here, you are using on click on anchor and then again binding click event on span in anchor, i hope you have a solid reason for it.

Comment: pointer-event:none; ,I'm getting error. Unknown property 'pointer-event'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213039/discussion-between-atul-and-anjana).